# Properly Nest SQL Queries

Tags: mysql, performance, nested

So I have been coding for a few months now, and I think I am getting the hang of working with MySQL. I can CRUD fairly well now. However, there is one pretty fundamental concept that's eluding me and I can't seem to figure out the best solution. The concept is basically centered around what the best practice is when one has to grab data from different tables - when not all data has joins on other related tables.

For example, let's say my task is to get all products and images from two separate tables, one called **products**, and the other called **images**. While all images have an associated product, *not all products have images*.

I started out writing my query:

```
SELECT product_name, productId FROM products
```

To first grab the pertinent product information. This is where I am stumped. What would be the best way to get the images for the products that actually have images? I cannot just join the image table as such:

```
SELECT product_name, image FROM products, images 
       WHERE images.image_product_Id = products.productId
```

because that would not pull back any product that does not have a join on the image table.

Right now, my solution is to run the first query, pull back the results, and then while I iterate through the product data row by row, I run an image subquery that reads:

```
SELECT image FROM images WHERE images.image_product_Id = '$productId'
```

where the variable $productId is that row's particular productId. If the query gives me results, I add the image data to the row.

This to me feels like terrible programming practice. Intuitively, I think that it can and should all be done in one query - but I cannot seem to figure out what that query would be.

I hope I was clear in how I worded this - and yes, I realize that to many this will be a very basic question. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Like a left outer join? Interesting haha, I just read up on it. It does seem like the solution.

Comment: Visual explain of several join types: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/  Outer joins (Left, right or Full)

Comment: Exact! That is what you are looking for. Btw. for detailed help you should mention what DBMS you are using. EDIT: Ok, DBMS has already been added. :)

Comment: I was really trying to refrain from asking this question! It really was just so simple at the end of the day. Thanks :) So I guess the query would be something like "SELECT product_name, image FROM products, LEFT INNER JOIN ON images WHERE images.image_product_Id = products.productId" ? Does that seem like the proper way to go about with that query?

Comment: LEFT [OUTER] JOIN, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html

Comment: Ah yes, I meant outer. I don't know why I wrote inner..! I am just so used to only writing inner joins. That makes sense - thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to acomplish what you need: The first is what you've already done. If you think that is inneficient, consider using joins:

- `table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON ...` will return  the rows of both tables that match each other (the issue you are facing with your `where`)
- `table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON ...` will return *all* the rows from `table1`, and the matching rows from `table2`, and if there are not matching rows in the second table, the columns will have `NULL` values
- `table2 RIGHT JOIN table2 ON ...` well... it's the same as above, but backwards

So, in your example, I would write a query like this:

```
select product_name, image
from products left join images on products.productId = images.image_product_id;
```

This query will return all the products and all the matching images, but if there's no image associated with a given product, the column value will be `NULL` for that product.

Try it, it may help you.

Comment: Perfect. Quasimido just alerted me to the concept of left joins, and funnily enough, we came up with the same solution. I knew it was such a basic concept, and I had only really been using inner joins so far. Thanks a lot for the help! :)

Comment: Happy to help! (If it works, up-vote it and/or accept it ;) )

Comment: @aamirl Yes, sometimes a short hint is enough and gives the chance to lern by making own thoughts. ;-)